# debugging firebase on local windows

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm trying to debug firebase function on my local windows

as described in https://medium.com/@mwebler/debugging-firebase-functions-with-vs-code-3afab528bb36

I do

```
set FIREBASE_CONFIG={  databaseURL: 'https://invoice-manager-251609.firebaseio.com',  storageBucket: 'invoice-manager-251609.appspot.com',   projectId: 'invoice-manager-251609'}

functions start
```

and get

```
┌────────┬────────┬─────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Status │ Name   │ Trigger │ Resource                                                        │
├────────┼────────┼─────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ FAILED │ upload │ HTTP    │ http://localhost:8010/invoice-manager-251609/us-central1/upload │
├────────┼────────┼─────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ FAILED │ tst    │ HTTP    │ http://localhost:8010/invoice-manager-251609/us-central1/tst    │
├────────┼────────┼─────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ FAILED │ tst1   │ HTTP    │ http://localhost:8010/invoice-manager-251609/us-central1/tst1   │
└────────┴────────┴─────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

if I do
`firebase emulators:start`

I get

> undefinedWarning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT.
>
> Initializing firebase-admin may fail[2019-10-06T11:44:51.932Z] 
>   @firebase/database: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url.
>
> Please use https://.firebaseio.com

I also tried:

```
functions debug tst1
```

and get:

> ERROR: Function worker crashed with exit code: 9
>   undefined(node:21096) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug

and

> node --debug-brk`are invalid. Please use`node --inspect`or`node --inspect-brk` instead.

I tried with `node-10` `and node-8`

I also tried this:
https://medium.com/@david_mccoy/build-and-debug-firebase-functions-in-vscode-73efb76166cf

and this
https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-functions-tutorial-debugging-local-functions-357c24829198

I get the same errors

whats going on?

how do I debugging firebase on local windows?

Comment: I don't believe that the current suite of Firebase emulators supports debugging functions.  That tutorial is kind of old.  If you're having an issue with the emulator, please post an issue to GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: This is not correct: I was able to debug the functions with Firebase emulators on my local windows with devTool step-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guides in the question are correct, but 
when running in Emulator, u have to set the db url manually

```
admin.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: "https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com"
  });
```

here is the full cmd list:

```
functions start

functions deploy --trigger-http --timeout 600s funcName

functions inspect funcName
```

After that u can use `chrome://inspect/` to connect to the process with the chrome debugger.

If you have issues, u can use:

```
functions logs read
```

NOTE: after `functions start` I still get the table with `FAILED` status - I ignore it